# Use of .a and .so file in ctypes

Tags: ctypes, .so, .a

I have a .a file and a .so file from a c program which I want to use in my ctypes python code. Need some help on which one to use and why

Comment: `.a` file is a **static library** (statically linked), while `.so` file is a **shared library** (dynamically linked). I think you can't use the static library at all.

Answer (score 1):

**(.a)** files are Archive libraries, and are statically linked. Thus, if there's any change in the library you need to compile and rebuild your program.

**(.so)** files are Shared Object files, and are linked during runtime. Thus, if there's a change in the library, you don't need to compile and rebuild your program.

For ctypes, you need to use the .so file.
Here is a good reference: [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html)